# Android : Showing keyboard moves my components up, i want to hide them instead

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added a LinearLayOut having some buttons My screen is RelativeLayOut it self

Here is the code for that linear layout manager

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Footer"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
```

Here is the problem:

There is an EditText component on the top and it pops a soft keyboard on the screen , and brings my Footer manager on top of the keyboard and eventually SHATTERS my whole UI.

What is the exact solution?

P.S. I have removed `android:gravity="bottom"` and  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` one by one but with hard luck i did not get desired result.

Thanks

Comment: After some sort of digging i come to know about this line `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but i don't know where to add it? in menifest or in main Relative layout of the screen?

Comment: Is that any possibility without removing, android:gravity="bottom" and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  ?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to manifest - to the corresponding activity:

```
  <activity android:name="MyActivity"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    ...
  </activity>
```

Comment: @Asahi any idea for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956157/selectionbar-is-hidden

Comment: This does not work on edittexts inside a webview, hides them.

Answer (score 19):

You probably want

```
<activity
     ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"> 
</activity>
```

That will prevent any layout changes when the soft keyboard is shown.

There is probably some confusion over this since it's currently missing from the documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: This save my day! Thanks!

Comment: Don't understand why this has way less votes. This is the one that works, thanks!

Comment: This should be the one! It worked for me while the others didn't!