# Garbage collector in java - set an object null

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Lets assume, there is a Tree object, with a root TreeNode object, and each TreeNode has leftNode and rightNode objects (e.g a BinaryTree object)

If i call:

```
myTree = null;
```

what really happens with the related TreeNode objects inside the tree? Will be garbage collected as well, or i have to set null all the related objects inside the tree object??

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Garbage collection in Java is performed on the basis of "reachability".  The JLS defines the term as follows:

> *"A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread."*

So long as an object is reachable<sup>1</sup>, it is not eligible for garbage collection.

The JLS leaves it up to the Java implementation to figure out how to determine whether an object *could* be accessible.  If the implementation cannot be sure, it is free to treat a theoretically unreachable object as reachable ... and not collect it.  (Indeed, the JLS allows an implementation to not collect anything, ever!  No practical implementation would do that though<sup>2</sup>.)

In practice, (conservative) reachability is calculated by tracing; looking at what can be reached by following references starting with the class (static) variables, and local variables on thread stacks.

---

Here's what this means for your question:

> If i call: `myTree = null;` what really happens with the related TreeNode objects inside the tree? Will be garbage collected as well, or i have to set null all the related objects inside the tree object??

Let's assume that `myTree` contains the last remaining reachable reference to the tree root.

1. Nothing *happens* immediately.
2. If the internal nodes *were previously* only reachable via the root node, then they are *now* unreachable, and eligible for garbage collection.  (In this case, assigning `null` to references to internal nodes is unnecessary.)
3. However, if the internal nodes were reachable via other paths, they are presumably *still* reachable, and therefore NOT eligible for garbage collection.  (In this case, assigning `null` to references to internal nodes is a mistake.  You are dismantling a data structure that something else might later try to use.)

If `myTree` *does not* contain the *last remaining* reachable reference to the tree root, then nulling the internal reference is a mistake for the same reason as in 3. above.

---

So when *should* you `null` things to help the garbage collector?

The cases where you need to worry are when *you* can figure out that that the reference in some cell (local, instance or class variable, or array element) won't be used again, but the compiler and runtime can't!  The cases fall into roughly three categories:

1. Object references in class variables ... which (by definition) never go out of scope.
2. Object references in local variables that are still in scope ... but won't be used.  For example:

   ```
    public List<Pig> pigSquadron(boolean pigsMightFly) {
      List<Pig> airbornePigs = new ArrayList<Pig>();
      while (...) {
        Pig piggy = new Pig();
        ...
        if (pigsMightFly) {
          airbornePigs.add(piggy);
        }
        ...
      }
      return airbornePigs.size() > 0 ? airbornePigs : null;
    }
   ```

   In the above, *we* know that if `pigsMightFly` is false, that the list object won't be used.  But no mainstream Java compiler could be expected to figure this out.
3. Object references in instance variables or in array cells where the data structure invariants mean that they won't be used.  @edalorzo's stack example is an example of this.

It should be noted that the compiler / runtime can sometimes figure out that an in-scope variable is effectively dead.  For example:

```
public void method(...) {
    Object o = ...
    Object p = ...
    while (...) {
        // Do things to 'o' and 'p'
    }
    // No further references to 'o'
    // Do lots more things to 'p'
}
```

Some Java compilers / runtimes *may* be able to detect that 'o' is not needed after the loop ends, and treat the variable as dead.

---

<sup>1 - In fact, what we are talking about here is **strong** reachability.  The GC reachability model is more complicated when you consider soft, weak and phantom references.  However, these are  not relevant to the OP's use-case.</sup>

<sup>2 - In Java 11 there is an experimental GC called the [Epsilon GC](https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-epsilon-gc-garbage-collector) that explicitly doesn't collect anything.</sup>

Comment: “*No reasonable implementation would do that though.*”…well, JDK 11 now ships with the option of a garbage collector that does nothing…

Comment: Hmmm ... OK, maybe it would be better to say "practical" rather than "reasonable".

Answer (score 4):

They will be garbage collected unless you have other references to them (probably manual). If you just have a reference to the tree, then yes, they will be garbage collected.

Comment: There's no guarantee that it will be garbage collected. It would be more correct to say "They will be eligible for garbage collection unless ...".

Answer (score 4):

You can't set an *object* to `null`, only a variable which might contain an pointer/reference to this object. The object itself is not affected by this. But if now no paths from any living thread (i.e. local variable of any running method) to your object exist, it will be garbage-collected, if and when the memory is needed. This applies to any objects, also the ones which are referred to from your original tree object.

Note that for local variables you normally not have to set them to `null` if the method (or block) will finish soon anyway.

Comment: I believe this is a critically important concept that we as seasoned engineers completely gloss over.  And we do so not because we don't understand it, but because it's difficult to think in very junior terms.  I wish Paulo's first statement was more often repeated.

Answer (score 4):

`myTree` is just a reference variable that previously pointed to an object in the heap. Now you are setting that to null. If you don't have any other reference to that object, then that object will be eligible for garbage collection.

To let the garbage collector remove the object `myTree` just make a call to `gc()` after you've set it to `null`

```
myTree=null;
System.gc();
```

Note that the object is removed only when there is no other reference pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you do not need to explicitly set objects to `null` to allow them to be GC'd. Objects are eligible for GC when there are no references to it (ignoring the `java.lang.ref.*` classes).

Comment: I am afraid that this statement could be misleading, although true. An object in an array may never be garbage collected unless you set the array index where it resides to null, provided that you are still using other objects in the array. This a classical memory leak in array-based stacks.

Answer (score 0):

An object gets collected when there are no more references to it.

In your case, the nodes referred to directly by the object formally referenced by `myTree` (the root node) will be collected, and so on.

This of course is not the case if you have outstanding references to nodes outside of the tree. Those will get GC'd once those references go out of scope (along with anything only they refer to)

Comment: An object is **eligible** to be GCd when there are no more references to it.

Comment: To be precise, yes, that is correct. However, being equally pedantic I can say with certainly that an object **won't** be GC'd if there is a reference to it.

Comment: @BrianRoach - to be even more precise, you should rephrase that to distinguish the differences in behaviour with different kinds of reference.

Comment: This isn't correct anyway, because there's no guarantee that any particular GC implementation is using reference counting as it's removal criterea.  In fact, it's very unlikely because of circular reference memory leaks.  The most common technique I've found is "mark and sweep", though there are others.

Comment: @tgm1024 - This answer doesn't talk about reference counting.  If it did, your critique would be correct ... but it doesn't.

Comment: @Stephen C, in the case of a circular reference between two objects, once the **external** references are nulled there are *still* references in play, and yet both objects become collected anyway.  Does this not fly in the face of "An object gets collected when there are no more references to it" ?

Comment: You are right.  This Answer should say *"An object gets collected when there are no more REACHABLE references to it."*  Read my Answer for more details.