# What happen if I set t1=null while t2 is assigned to t1?

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection

```
Test t1 = new Test();
Test t2 = t1;
t1 = null;
```

What will happen to t2? Will the object be garbage collect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690309/garbage-collector-in-java-set-an-object-null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happen if I set t1=null while t2 is assigned to t1

The confusion is right there in the title: `t2` is *not* assigned to `t1`. This line:

```
Test t2 = t1;
```

copies the *value* that's in `t1` into `t2`. There is no ongoing link (other than that they have the same value, which in this case is a thing called an *object reference* that tells the JVM where to find an object in memory).

I like some ASCII-art when dealing with these kinds of questions:

The line

```
Test t1 = new Test();
```

gives us this in memory:

```
+----------+
| t1       |---+
+----------+   |   +-------------+
               +-->| Test object |
                   +-------------+
```

Then the line:

```
Test t2 = t1;
```

gives us this:

```
+----------+
| t1       |---+
+----------+   |   +-------------+
               +-->| Test object |
+----------+   |   +-------------+
| t2       |---+
+----------+
```

then

```
t1 = null;
```

gives us:

```
+----------+
| t1: null |
+----------+       +-------------+
               +-->| Test object |
+----------+   |   +-------------+
| t2       |---+   
+----------+
```

`t2` is completely unaffected by antyhing you do to `t1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. With the ASCII -art, everything becomes clear.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens to `t2`. It still refers to the same `Test` instance that was originally referred by both `t1` and `t2`, and as long as that reference exists, this instance can't be garbage collected.