# getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable stretches background

Tags: android

I created a background image which fits exactly into the device display without status bar and actionbar. That means the whole height of my device is 1280 pixels.
Without statusbar and actionbar it is 1038 pixels. My background image is exactly 1038 pixels high. When i set the image as the background of my layout:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.setBackground(Helper.loadDrawableFromFile(this.getResources(), Helper.getBackgroundLoginImagePath()));

    ....
}
```

It fits perfectly into the screen as i want it to. the problem is that i have a scroll view and when i want to type something in my edittexts the keyboard pops up and my background image gets clinched.

So i changed my code to set the background image to the window in my activities onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    this.getWindow().setBackground(Helper.loadDrawableFromFile(this.getResources(), Helper.getBackgroundLoginImagePath()));

    ...
}
```

But for some reason the background image now gets stretched so that the height is bigger than the original and i cant see the whole image. (its about 60 pixels to high).

What is happening there? Why is 'setBackgroundDrawable' stretching my image?

**EDIT**

When i do the following in a dialog fragment, which in my opinion is exactly the same as doing it in an activity, works perfectly:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(Helper.loadDrawableFromFile(this.getResources(), Helper.getBackgroundLoginImagePath()));

    ...
}
```

so why isnt it working for an activity?

Answer (score 2):

You have to scale the image if you don't want to be stretched. To do that it would be better for me to use the following into the R.layout.activity_login:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

            <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"  
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"  
                 android:layout_gravity="center"  
                 android:src="@drawable/yourdrawable"  
                 android:scaleType="centerInside">  
            </ImageView>  

 </FrameLayout>
```

The CENTER_INSIDE will "scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding)". 
For more info regarding the scaling types you can have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Finally, it's worth mentioning that the setBackgroundDrawable was deprecated in API level 16. And the documentation propose to use setBackground(Drawable) instead.

Comment: I never used 'setBackgroundDrawable' and the background image is already perfectly scaled. As i mentioned in my opening post it fits perfectly when i add it as a background to my layout but gets stretched when i set it as a background image of the window

Comment: @Mulgard I suppose that the problem could be that the image is trying to cover the whole window. And therefore is getting stretched. It might be the scaling type that is being used by the method.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want your view to be pushed by the keyboard add

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

You can use ImageView instead of view. setBackground()

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516216/how-to-avoid-soft-keyboard-pushing-up-my-layout) related question.

Comment: Ehm... but thats the point... i want my view to be pushed, i just dont want my background immage to get clinched. thats why i wanted to add it as a background of the window. but when i do it it gets stretched (for no reason because it perfeclty fits into the screen size).

Comment: And i have to say that this does not work anyway. i set scrollcontainer to false and added ajustPan to windowSoftInputMode and the image still gets clinched when keyboard pops up.