# keyboard pushing up footer

Tags: java, android, xml, keyboard

I have a footer in my application, but i am having a problem where the footer gets pushed up each time the keyboard comes out. I have added the `"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` code into my manifest file but it hasn't fixed it.
Below is the regular view with keyboard hidden.

[image: This is the normal view with keyboard hidden]

This is what my view looks like with the keyboard visible. I would like the keyboard to cover the footer rather than push it up.

[image: second]

Below is my code for the layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/icons_container"
        tools:context=".app.LoginActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolBar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/loginbannerimage"
                android:contentDescription="banner"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Login progress -->
                <include layout="@layout/custom_progress_bar"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/toolBar"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Welcome To MAP"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="20sp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:padding="5dp"
                                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardBg"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                                android:padding="0dp">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:padding="15dp">
                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/email"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:hint="Email here"
                                        android:maxLines="1"
                                        android:singleLine="true" />

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/password"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:hint="Password"
                                        android:imeActionLabel="Password here"
                                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                                        android:maxLines="1"
                                        android:singleLine="true" />

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                                        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                        android:text="Sign-in"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:elevation="5dp"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

            <include layout="@layout/footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            </include>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Im facing the same problem.. did you found solution ?   android:isScrollContainer="false" this not worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is related with the scrollView, adding line below to the scrollview might solve the issue

android:isScrollContainer="false"

as stated here
[How to avoid soft keyboard pushing up my layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516216/how-to-avoid-soft-keyboard-pushing-up-my-layout)

Answer (score 0):

It  is because your footer has a height value of

```
wrap_content
```

and the other part/s (the ones being compressed) have a value of

```
match_parent
```

and if it does not have a certain value or wrap_content it will be compressed to accommodate the keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this in your scrollView. This solved my problem.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```