# Android BottomSheetBehavior with Keyboard adjustResize

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I have the following layout in an activity.

```
<CoordinatorLayout ...>
  <ScrollView ...>
    <LinearLayout
      ...
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <!-- Some stuff -->
      <EditText ...>
      <!-- Some more stuff -->
      <View
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_extender"
        ...>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ...
    app:layout_behavior="android...BottomSheetBehavior">
    <!-- Even more stuff -->
  </LinearLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

and I want that the keyboard shouldn't push up the `bottom_sheet` but it should push up the `keyboard_extender`. Please note that the `bottom_sheet` is not a `BottomSheetDialog` but just a view using the `android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior`. This can't be changed to a `BottomSheetDialog` because I want the rest of the screen to remain active at the same time as the `bottom_sheet`

I never set the visibility of the `bottom_sheet` to `View.GONE`. I only change its state from `BottomSheetBehavior.EXPANDED` to `BottomSheetBehavior.COLLAPSED` and back. Also, I want the `bottom_sheet` to be visible only when the keyboard isn't.

Since I need that the `keyboard_extender` should always be above the keyboard, I have set in the AndroidManifest.xml that `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` (which I assume is unavoidable)

I have a method which when called should hide the keyboard and show the `bottom_sheet`, but the problem I'm facing is that the `bottom_sheet` starts animating to `BottomSheetBehavior.EXPANDED` at the same time that the keyboard starts hiding, and when the keyboard starts hiding, the screen is actually resized because of the `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and the `bottom_sheet` starts expanding from the top of the keyboard and it doesn't move down along with the keyboard. So, when the keyboard completely hides, the `bottom_sheet` is actually sitting in the middle of the screen (just above the height of the keyboard).

Ideally, I'd like that the keyboard starts hiding and the `bottom_sheet` starts expanding at the same time, but the `bottom_sheet` starts expanding from the bottom of the screen and not the top of the keyboard.

The very hacky fix I'm currently using to overcome this issue is to delay the expanding of the `bottom_sheet` by `SoftInput.KEYBOARD_POPUP_DELAY`, which seems to be working for the time being. Is there any cleaner alternative?

Comment: I solved this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956520/7719690 I hope it helps.