# Soft keyboard pushing layout

Tags: java, android, layout, view, keyboard

I have been trying many solutions out there for preventing the soft keyboard from pushing my layout when it appears. However, all solutions did not work.

Simply, I want everything in my layout (buttons, imageViews, Background, textViews, textEdits) to stay in place when soft keyboard is shown. I do not care about what it will cover.

I tried all of the following and all produced the same output and do not work:

1. (did not work) I tried writing `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in my `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. (did not work) I tried writing `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`in my`onCreate()` though it did not work
3. I tried writing `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
   in my `AndroidManifest.xml` and also did not work
4. (did not work) I tried writing `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` in my `AndroidManifest.xml`
5. (did not work) I also tried writing `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

All the above solutions produced the following snapshot:

The actual layout looks like this (this is what I want it to keep looking when soft keyboard is active):

Any idea of how to prevent this?

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xxxxxxx">
    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    <!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->


    <!--Real Ad ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/relativeLayout"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/relativeLayout"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5739450654089125/9466012825"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitScore"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ourScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/adView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/theirScoreTextInput"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ourScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/adView"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/theirTextFieldDescription" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ourScoreTextInput"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="389dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/theirScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/theirScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/submitScore"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ourTextFieldDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theirTextFieldDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:text="@string/their_score"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/theirScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.472"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/theirScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/theirScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.283" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ourTextFieldDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/our_score"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        ads:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/theirTextFieldDescription"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ourTextFieldDescription"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ourScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/ourScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/ourScoreTextInput"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/theirTextFieldDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theirScoreSheet"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#1FFF"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/background"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/frameLayout"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/theirScoreSheetDescription"
        ads:layout_goneMarginLeft="16dp"
        ads:layout_goneMarginRight="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ourScoreSheet"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="#1FFF"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/theirScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/frameLayout"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/background"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/theirScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        ads:layout_goneMarginLeft="16dp"
        ads:layout_goneMarginRight="16dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/background"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gear"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gear"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gear"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:srcCompat="@drawable/gear" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theirScoreSheetDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/their_score"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/theirScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/theirScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/theirScoreTextInput" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ourScoreTotalLarge"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="75sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ourScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/ourScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/ourScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ourScoreSheet" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theirScoreTotalLarge"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="75sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ourScoreTotalLarge"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/theirScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/theirScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ourScoreTotalLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ourScoreSheetDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/our_score"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/theirScoreSheetDescription"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/ourScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/ourScoreSheet"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/theirScoreSheetDescription" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:alpha="0.0"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/gear"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/gear"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/gear"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gear" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ads:layout_constraintGuide_end="364dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try `stateHidden|adjustNothing` or `adjustResize`

Comment: I tried both as shown in my write up above and did not work

Comment: show your xml and manifest file

Comment: your background image u take in your scrollview right ? @Adeeb

Comment: there is no scroll view in my xml only (textViews, buttons, textEdits and imageViewes)

Comment: ok where u Set your background image in xml or java ? @Adeeb

Comment: in my xml file actually

Comment: can you post your your_layout.xml code?

Comment: Please find it above. I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your Background image in xml file

Set Background image in java file using below code:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.banner1));
```

Comment: this is good. it fixed the background image. However, the other objects are still moving when the softkeyboard appears

Comment: Show me your `XML` file

Comment: please see above. I added it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same thing. While staying in one Activity, sometimes the soft keyboard would cause re-layouts and sometimes it wouldn't, depending on what Fragment I had loaded. Finally I figured it out. It was caused by a RecyclerView being visible:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

That's it. If the Fragment I had loaded had a visible RecyclerView, the soft keyboard would cause re-layout. If not, it wouldn't. It even causes a re-layout of stuff that isn't part of the Fragment that contains the RecyclerView.

That's how it looks in a ConstraintLayout. But it could also be in a RelativeLayout. If its visibility is "gone", the soft keyboard's appearance doesn't cause re-layout. If it's "visible", the soft keyboard's appearance causes a re-layout of the whole Activity. I don't know what versions of Android this "works" on, and I don't know whether it's intentional.

I know you don't have one, but maybe something else in your .xml does the same thing, or has a RecyclerView in it. I'd surmise that the presence of the RecyclerView causes the SoftInputMode to be set. You could consider waiting for your view to finish laying out, then changing SoftInputMode, and see if it sticks.

Comment: This seems to be a more informed discussion with better alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516216/how-to-avoid-soft-keyboard-pushing-up-my-layout