# Hide Keyboard does not re-expand the layout

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-recyclerview, android-design-library

I implemented `CoordinatorLayout` with `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` to hide toolbar when scrolling and everything working greet.
The problem appears when i implemented search view.
Here is my `activity_main` layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my `fragment_layout` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/projects_swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/projects_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Normal layout `RecyclerView`
[image: Normal layout (RecyclerView)]

[image: Keyboard shown]

**The problem here when keyboard is hidden.**
[image: keyboard hidden]

Comment: How do you hide the keyboard?

Comment: It's by default when press back button or click on search icon.

Comment: Does your application set this flag in Android Manifest file:
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: No i does not set anything.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

Comment: @Ahmed I would expect for the `adjustResize` flag to expand the layout the moment the soft keyboard is hidden, however I'm using an AppBarLayout with a recyclerview inside a Fragment ona ViewPager and I have the exact same problem as exposed by @hema18

Comment: I realize this question is ancient, but how were you able to solve this problem? I've got a similar situation that is causing me a lot of head scratching...

Answer (score 1):

You can control the expandable behavior of the appBarLayout :

first By putting these lines in Manifest, you disable the appbar collapse effect due to the keyboard when it shows and when it hides.

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
   ...
</activity>
```

Then, simply expand/collapse appbar whenever you want :

```
appbar.setExpanded(true); / appbar.setExpanded(false);
```

you could collapse when EditText hasFocus, and expand when outter views get touch..

```
(someView.setOnTouchListener ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered here:
[Android : Showing keyboard moves my components up, i want to hide them instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301422/android-showing-keyboard-moves-my-components-up-i-want-to-hide-them-instead)

> Add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to manifest - to the corresponding activity:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
   ...
</activity>
```